# Connect web form to a web service with security

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services, api

I was asked to make some wordpress site where the user puts some votes for a list of guys, and then sends this data to a web service which saves the vote in another database.

Before sending the data, the wordpress site asks to log in and the user logs in with facebook.

The web service has a restriction where a given user can only vote once within 24 hours.

They asked me to secure the web service and I thought about using an API key configured in the wordpress set and send the form post with the api key in the header. I don't have users in the web service.

Is this the correct way? Could you explain me point by point how would you do it?

Thanks

**EDIT**

- I have to make both wordpress and the web service
- The Web Server is in https
- I'm asking about what to have into account to have a reliable web service
- The user who sends the votes is logged in in wordpress

Comment: Are you creating the web service?

Comment: This seems like too broad a question.  There are any number of security aspects you need to look at - user authentication, server-to-server authentication, time-based authorization for user to vote, form validation, transmission security, data validation, XSS protection, etc. what specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I've edited the question with some points

Answer (score 0):

If the web service is configured to use https then any data sent to it would be encrypted.

You will want to make sure any requests to the web service only come from authenticated users, though. If the user is authenticated to the WordPress site, are you using cookies or a session id that the web service can also use to authenticate the user?